ASP.NET Core 7 MVC : how to submit IEnumerable model to controller?
I have simple grid filled from an IEnumerable model and I can't pass it to the controller:
@model IEnumerable<SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel>

<form method="post" asp-action="VykazSkupinaCreateMiddle2" id="KlientiSkupinyForm" asp-controller="Work">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-10">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Zápis výkazu pro kliety skupiny:  @skupinaText </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 text-end">
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

    <table class="table table-hover" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th scope="col">
                    Klient
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    Přítomen
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var obj in Model)
                {
                    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].Klient" value="@obj.Klient" hidden />
                    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].Id" value="@obj.Id" hidden />
                    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].Skupina" value="@obj.Skupina" hidden />
                    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].UserId" value="@obj.UserId" hidden />
                    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].KlientName" value="@obj.KlientName" hidden />
                    <tr class="@(i%2==0?"table-primary":"table-secondary")">
                        <td>
                            @obj.KlientName
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[@i].Pritomen" checked="@obj.Pritomen" value="@obj.Pritomen" />
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a asp-controller="Work" asp-action="AktivniKlienti" class="btn btn-secondary" style="width:250px">Zpět na seznam klientu</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 text-end">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:250px"><i class="breadcrumb-item bi-pencil-square"></i> Založ výkazy</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>

Razor view page is filled fine.
<tbody>
    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].Klient" value="3026" hidden />
    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].Id" value="6615" hidden />
    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].Skupina" value="121" hidden />
    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].UserId" value="18b4adfd-7b08-4390-a23e-06a338842c77" hidden />
    <input name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].KlientName" value="Mia14Nia77 Milena Hus&#xE1;rkov&#xE1;" hidden />
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <td>
            Mia14Nia77 Milena Hus&#xE1;rkov&#xE1;
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel[0].Pritomen" checked="checked" value="value" />
        </td>
    </tbody>

But after submitting the model, in the controller, it is always empty.
This is my controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult VykazSkupinaCreateMiddle2(IEnumerable<SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel> klienti)
{
        string? userId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);

        int id = klienti.First().Skupina;
        // etc ...
}

Model
    public class SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Skupina")]
    public int Skupina { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Uživatel")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Klient id")]
    public int Klient { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Přítomen")]
    public bool Pritomen { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Klient")]
    public string KlientName { get; set; }


}

Please, could you tell me, how is it possible?
Thanks
This text is only for nothing, because I can't post this post via: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
But I think that there is every necessary detail included...

Can you add the SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel model declaration to the post, please?

Model added - thanx

Because of in the
public IActionResult VykazSkupinaCreateMiddle2(IEnumerable<SkupinaKlientiVykazyModel> klienti) 

action method the parameter named as klienti to make the MVC binding work properly it is necessary to use the same name in the view code:
foreach (var obj in Model)
{
    <input name="klienti[@i].Klient" value="@obj.Klient" hidden />
    <input name="klienti[@i].Id" value="@obj.Id" hidden />
    <input name="klienti[@i].Skupina" value="@obj.Skupina" hidden />
    <input name="klienti[@i].UserId" value="@obj.UserId" hidden />
    <input name="klienti[@i].KlientName" value="@obj.KlientName" hidden />
    <tr class="@(i%2==0?"table-primary":"table-secondary")">
        <td>
            @obj.KlientName
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="klienti[@i].Pritomen" checked="@obj.Pritomen" value="@obj.Pritomen" />
            </td>
    </tr>
    i++;
}


You saved my night. Thanx a lot!
